# ASP.NET MVC routing catch-all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Is there an article somewhere explaining exactly how the route matching works and what it is capable of?

For example, how would I write a route to catch everything, so that:

> ```
> /
> /something
> /something/else
> /something/else/again
> ```

all get mapped to the same controller action, with the URL passed as a parameter?

```
{*anything}
```

The above doesn't seem to work. Can it not handle slashes inside arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below catches *almost* everything.

```
http://www.mysite.com/
```

for instance would still be routed to default.aspx,I think. But something like

http://www.mysite.com/some/page/that/doesnt/exist

would be caught by the TestRouteHandler. The {*fields} route specifier should wind up in the RequestContext.RouteData object passed to the router so you can do whatever you want. However, at that point, you're basically implementing a rewrite engine.

```
public class Routes
{
    public static void Register(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // setup legacy url routing
        routes.Add(new Route("{*fields}",new TestRouteHandler()));
    }
}

public class TestRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public virtual IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Page page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("/default.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
        return page;
    }

}
```

alternatively, you can specify a top-level route like

```
    routes.Add(new Route("dave/{*fields}",new TestRouteHandler()));
```

which will catch items like.

```
http://www.mysite.com/dave
http://www.mysite.com/dave/test/parameter
http://www.mysite.com/dave/virtually/infinite/number/of/items/goes/here
```

Comment: i was doing this but it wasnt working, now it is :s wierd. must have been one of those friday moments! thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

I have had to handle that in past using this method:

```
public ActionResult Something(string anything)
{
     var anythings = anything.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And this route:

```
"something/{*anything}"
```

And to catch everything. This is probably a smell but...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Show(string anything)
   {
      Response.Write(anything);
      return null;
   }
```

Then before the Default route...

```
routes.MapRoute("anything", "{*anything}", new {controller="Home",action="Show"});
```

Comment: what about the root, or things that dont begin with "something"?